# Python - For a url, how to check if the webserver is available or exists ? (confused)

Tags: python, webserver, urllib2, urllib

For a `url` entered by the user :

> check that is any webserver hosting the domain name or not ?

For example :

```
url='laksjdfaksdfjajdfaljewoifjadslkjflkasjrlwkejk.com'
```

> Now, the above url does-not exists, so there is no point of check for any HTTP error codes since, no server is there that will reply back.

So, how to detect such url ?

```
isServerUp() ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should open the url for you; obviously change how you want to say that the url has failed to open. The docs are: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

```
from urllib2 import *

req = Request(url)

# Try to open the url
try: 
    reponse = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError, e:
    url = None
except URLError, e:
    url = None
```

EDIT: Indentation fixed

Comment: Please fix the indentation, I don't think that will run.

Comment: @dancek thank you, that's what I get for copying and pasting.

Comment: +1, but please note that import * is usually a bad practice cluttering your namespace and creating less maintainable code. either explicitly import what you need, or import the module.

Comment: its giving error : ValueError: unknown url type: `thisisaurlthatdoesnotexists.com`

Comment: @Yugal the url must be a string and must contain the http part: (`"http://thisisaurlthatdoesnotexists.com"`)

Comment: Ok, that worked, But how do you check for a Url .i.e. what if I deliberately skip the http part ?